# how do you include python .py file in flutter using chaquopy?

Tags: python, flutter, dart, chaquopy

I was try to include .py file inside my flutter project to use sklearn and numpy ,was able understand how to include .py file but could not understand how to call it in the flutter main.dart application, a small example will be helpful
Thank You

Comment: please add what you tried until now and some code. Thanks

Comment: i added the chaquopy.dart file in my project and was able to add python folder with the script.py file in it as well main problem was how to call that python file inside my flutter project using the chaquopy.executeCode command and get the result in the map

Answer (score 0):

Chaquopy lets you access Python code through a [Java API](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/java.html). So in Flutter, you should use the same technique as you'd use to call any other Java API, which appears to be ["platform channels"](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).

There's an example [here](https://github.com/jaydangar/chaquopy_flutter) which you might find useful.

Comment: I already was using chaquopy, was able to install and include the chaquopy but the problem was when i tried to call the pythonn file into the flutter project or get the .py file to execute and give me the result to show in flutter that was the problem. I did see the example but wasnt able to understand how the implement this. A syntax would be helpful of Chaquopy.executeCode()

Comment: The linked example is about interpreting arbitrary Python code at runtime, which probably isn't what you want. However, it does show how to use the platform channels feature, which you could adapt for your own app. I can't be any more specific because I don't have any Flutter experience myself.

Comment: thank you for your help, I will certainly try using the example only

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call .py file, plugin calls that file internally for you. you just need to call `Chaquopy.executeCode()` function, with you code in it. I am stating an example for you here:

suppose you want to print a number, and below is your code :

```
a = 10
print(10)
```

what you need to do is, take the code from textinput as a string and put it in `Chaquopy.execute()` method:

```
code = 'a=10\nprint(a)'
Chaquopy.executeCode(code)
```

hope this helps. you don't need to call anything internally.